# Windows 10 Shortcut Target - Change Working Directory?

Tags: windows, shortcut

I have this file structure:

```
Program_Folder
   -> Program.exe
Data_Folder
   -> Data1
   -> Data2
   -> Data3
   etc.
```

Adding an absolute path to each data file works but I quickly run out of characters. The limit is 260 characters, I believe. Is it possible to change the working directory once and then add all the data files?

I'm also wondering if this can be done with a relative path. Something similar to the command line "cd.." "cd Data_Folder". Can this be done?

In the shortcut:

```
Target: C:\Program_Folder\Program.exe C:\Data_Folder\Data1 C:\Data_Folder\Data2 C:\Data_Folder\Data3
```

Comment: Please clarify the problem and what you have tried so far. Post some code of you creating the shortcut...

Answer (score -1):

Since I'm getting dislikes instead of an answer I guess I will try and answer my own question.

What I ended up doing instead of a shortcut was a batch file. I put this file in the Data_Folder making this the working directory for the batch file. Then I made a shortcut to the batch file instead. This works but it feels a bit hacky.  Anyone have a better solution?

```
C:\Program_Folder\Program.exe ^
Data1 ^
Data2 ^
Data3 ^
```